# Vectorize piecewize defined function (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, vectorization, piecewise

I'm trying to vectorize a piecewise defined function in Python. The function I want to define is the following:

[Piecewise defined function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOMh4.jpg)

I tried to define it as:

```
def g(x,n,w):
    global y
    for i in range(n):
        if i+w*i < x < w*i +i+1:
            y=x-w*i
        elif i + w*(i-1)<=x<= i + w*i:
            y=i
    return(y)
```

It seems to be working when I call it. If I for example write:

```
n=10
w=1
s=lambda x:g(x,n,w)
```

Then the function s seems to be doing what I think it should be doing. However I want to apply it to a whole vector and for this I thought I could use the `numpy` function "vectorize":

```
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(0,4,20)
sv=np.vectorize(s)
```

However, if I apply the function `sv` to the vector `x` it only return integervalues. For example for `0<=t<1`, `s(t)=t`, but if the same `t` is a part of the vector `x` it will be a `0` in `sv(x)`.

Comment: Set the `otypes` parameter of `vectorize`

Comment: `vectorize` isn't going to help you speedwise.  And correct use can be tricky, as you found.  I think you are better of trying to generate these values without `vectorize` or iteration on `x`.

Comment: @hjpaul Thank you! I added otypes=[np.float64] in the np.vectorize function and its working.